# Not able to generate PDF via eDrawing

Tags: pdf

Not able to open the generated PDF via Adobe Reader. It say the file is corrupted.

```
        const string PRINTER_NAME = "CutePDF Writer";
        const int AUTO_SOURCE = 7;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Opened {0}\n", fileName));
        m_Ctrl.SetPageSetupOptions(EMVPrintOrientation.eLandscape, 9, 100, 100, 1, AUTO_SOURCE, PRINTER_NAME, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        m_Ctrl.Print5(false, fileName, true, false, true, EMVPrintType.eScaleToFit, 1, 0, 0, true, 1, 1, "C:\Test\Output.pdf");
```

when i set to print with "Microsoft Print to PDF" the PDF is generated was able to open from Adobe Reader.

I tried with CutePDF, PDF24 but no luck. Do we need to update registery for CutePDF